# Angular 6 HttpClient response has only some headers

Tags: angular, http-headers, httpclient

We have a use case in our REST implementation where it returns a special header that we use for pagination and determining the number of pages.  I have modified the HttpClient options to observe the entire response.  The response I see in chrome has this in its headers:

[image]

The special header is Content-Range and I see that in Chrome.  When trying to get the Content-Range header in my subscription response, it is null.  When debugging it turns out the headers array only has a subset of the actual headers.

[image]

I see folks talking about changing a server option to allow.  We go through a servlet proxy.  In development, all our responses have this:

```
private void setAccessControlHeaders(HttpServletResponse resp) {
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
    resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
}
```

Is there something else I need to do to get access to a custom header?

Comment: Yep, add [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers) as well

Comment: This could be helpful: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Answer (score 0):

I know that you need to add it like below

```
resp.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Content-Range");
```

But can you tell me where this function you have is located?